# Create timeseries from groupby result in Spark dataframe using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe which can be simplified as the following:

```
Party       CounterParty       timestamp    
id_1        id_2               01/01/16
id_2        id_3               01/01/16
id_1        id_2               14/01/16
id_4        id_1               03/01/16
id_2        id_3               01/01/16
id_1        id_1               01/02/16
id_1        id_2               30/01/16
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a timeseries for every unique pair of Party and CounterParty. The goal is to plot and further analyse this time series data for each pair.
In pseudo code:

```
pairs = df.grouby(Party,CounterParty)
list = []
for i in each pair:
   find all timestamps and append to list

//DO OTHER STUFF
```

The groupby is not a problem but I don't know how to proceed afterwards.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your timeseries data are not huge arrays, it's better to let spark do the job, like this:

```
df.groupBy('Party', 'CounterParty') \
    .agg(collect_list('timestamp').alias('timestamps')).collect()
```